# Custom setter for segue not seeing the object I'm sending to it in iPhone Master/Detail storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, segue, setter, master-detail

Basically, I'm trying to send an object from the master view to the detail view by way of a custom setter. However, as soon as the setter gets called in the detail view, the app immediately crashes. I'm not too good at debugging, but I think it's because the object isn't making it to the setter -- it's seeing it as nil. Could be wrong about that, though.

Here's the code for the segue in the master view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    CCNewsItem *theNewsItem = self.listOfNewsItems[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Preparing to pass: %@", theNewsItem);
    [[segue destinationViewController] setSelectedNewsItem:theNewsItem];

    }
}
```

And here it is for the setter in the detail view:

```
   - (void)setSelectedNewsItem:(CCNewsItem *)newItem
{
    if (self.selectedNewsItem != newItem) {
    self.selectedNewsItem = newItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
    }
}
```

It crashes exactly on the `- (void)setSelectedNewsItem:(CCNewsItem *)newItem` line. I've made super-sure that the object being passed is valid (I log it to double check, and all seems well), but it seems that it either isn't making it to the setter or it's somehow exploding when it hits it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**As requested, here's the logs/exception**

This is what my NSLog shows on the object I'm trying to pass:

```
2013-11-02 14:18:23.660 Curtis Consulting[14862:60b] Preparing to pass: <CCNewsItem: 0x14e70580>
```

When the app stops on the setter's first line (I'm not sure why; I have all breakpoints disabled), it shows the values of newItem (the passed object) as:

```
newItem CCNewsItem *    nil 0x00000000
NSObject    NSObject        
_headline   NSString *  nil 
_body   NSString *  nil 
_url    NSURL * nil
```

**Edit 2**

Since, as near as I can tell, there is no way to copy the error it's showing (in a green bar at the right, but I don't have any breakpoints turned on), here's my transcription of it:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x27c84ff8)
```

Comment: Show the details of your logging and the exception.

Comment: I'm afraid the logging doesn't show much, but I'll put it up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setter method change:

```
if (self.selectedNewsItem != newItem) {
self.selectedNewsItem = newItem;
```

to

```
if (_selectedNewsItem != newItem) {
_selectedNewsItem = newItem;
```

Because your current code has an infinite loop calling the accessor method. Be sure you know what using `self.` means...

Comment: Thanks so much! I've always been confused by when to use `self.` and when to use `_`, and it's clearly bitten me badly here.

Comment: Basically just use `_` in the custom setter for the property and the `init` method. Remember that `self.` calls the accessor method (even if you haven't implemented it explicitly).